# invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int'

Tags: c++

this is C++

[Error] invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

```
void boite(int ligne,int colonne,int i,int s[],int k)
{
     int n;
     n= s_boite[i][ligne][colonne];  // i numero de la boite 
    for(;n!=0;n/=2)
        s[k--]=n%2;
}
```

more additions : s_boit

```
static const int s_boite[8][4][16] = { { {14, 4, 13, 1, 2, 15, 11, 8, 3, 10, 6, 12, 5, 9, 0, 7}, { 0, 15, 7, 4, 14, 2, 13, 1, 10, 6, 12, 11, 9, 5, 3, 8}, { 4, 1, 14, 8, 13, 6, 2, 11, 15, 12, 9, 7, 3, 10, 5, 0}, {15, 12, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 7, 5, ...ext
```

the call for this function :

```
for(i=0;i<8;i++) // appeller les boittes 
 {
        ligne = resultat[i][0]*2 + resultat[i][5]; // le 1er et le dernier bit converit a au decimal 
        for(j=0;j<4;j++) // 4 bits du milieu 
        {colonne += resultat[i][j+1]*puiss(2,(3-j));}//acumulation en calculant la colone (traduction en decimal)
         boite(ligne,colonne,i,mat,(4*(i+1)-1)); //mat pour sauvgarder le resultat 
}
```

Comment: How and where is `s_boite` defined?

Comment: More information please.....

Comment: static const int s_boite[8][4][16] = {
 
   {
   {14,  4, 13,  1,  2, 15, 11,  8,  3, 10,  6, 12,  5,  9,  0,  7},
   { 0, 15,  7,  4, 14,  2, 13,  1, 10,  6, 12, 11,  9,  5,  3,  8},
   { 4,  1, 14,  8, 13,  6,  2, 11, 15, 12,  9,  7,  3, 10,  5,  0},
   {15, 12,  8,  2,  4,  9,  1,  7,  5, ...ext

Comment: Is this C or is this C++?

Comment: @user3188097 Commenting on your question does not improve your question. Please improve your question by editing it.

Comment: I removed the [tag:c] tag for you.

Comment: Why don't you use a, let's say `struct`, instead of that messy array?

Comment: Please show us the call to this function

Comment: your new edit doesn't help as it's still not enough to get compiling code.

Comment: Is the error message you are giving `[Error] invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]` indicating a source file and line number that you are showing in your problem statement? That's not a complete error message. The compiler would tell you source file and line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code (slightly modified) that is compiled without any warnings. Please check, where is the actual root cause:

```
#include <iostream>

static const int s_boite[1][1][16] = { { {14, 4, 13, 1, 2, 15, 11, 8, 3, 10, 6, 12, 5, 9, 0, 7}}};

void boite(int ligne,int colonne,int i,int s[],int k)
{
     int n;
     n= s_boite[i][ligne][colonne];  // i numero de la boite
    for(;n!=0;n/=2)
        s[k--]=n%2;
}

int main() {
        int a[2] = {-1, -1};
        boite(0,3,0,a,0);
        std::cout << "a[0] = " << a[0] << std::endl; // =1
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: am still getting the same error

Comment: @user3188097 Am I understand right you have tried to compile my version of the code and it fails at compilation time?

Comment: user3188097: can you post the exact command line you used to the compiler and the exact output you get?

Comment: @user3188097 Could you provide with compiler version as well as exact error output?

Comment: i use Dev c++ compiler , and i get the previous error

Comment: @user3188097 and what line number?

Comment: in this line :  n= s_boite[i][ligne][colonne];

Answer (score 1):

I edited your source code a little bit and compiled using g++ with the -Wextra and -Wall flags. Compiles for me, got a warning because I took the 3rd dimension away. Shouldn't be relevant.

```
static const int s_boite[8][16] =
{
{14, 4, 13, 1, 2, 15, 11, 8, 3, 10, 6, 12, 5, 9, 0, 7},
{ 0, 15, 7, 4, 14, 2, 13, 1, 10, 6, 12, 11, 9, 5, 3, 8},
{ 4, 1, 14, 8, 13, 6, 2, 11, 15, 12, 9, 7, 3, 10, 5, 0},
};

void boite(int ligne,int colonne,int i,int s[],int k)
{
     int n;
     n= s_boite[i][ligne];  // i numero de la boite 
    for(;n!=0;n/=2)
        s[k--]=n%2;
}

int main(void)
{
        int ess[32];
        boite(1, 0, 1, ess, 16);
        return 0;
}
```